# Make an app where audio recording starts as soon as the app is opened

Tags: java, android, audio-recording

I tried to make an app where the recording starts as soon as the app is opened and there is no need to click a button to start the recording ... i tried to search for similar tutorials but each one had buttons which triggered the start recording in android studio or in any app... i want the trigger of starting recording to be the event of opening app itself.. that's all you have to do to start recording and the recording should stop when the app is terminated or closed. can anyone please help me?

Comment: "tried to make" how? Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply make `onStart` or `onCreate` of MainActivity call the same code that `onClick` would if you *had a button*

Or make `MainActivity implements View.onClickListener`, then have `onStart` or `onCreate` just call `this.onClick(null)`

Comment: Why should I post if none was in the question to begin with?